# Pass function argument as formula

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a code of my VBA script:

```
Function custom_if_formula(condition)
    MsgBox(condition)    
End Function
```

I am pasting the formula to any cell:

```vb
=custom_if_formula(B1="something")
```

The result in MsgBox is: `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Is it possible get in MsgBox as a result `B1="something"` as instead?

A pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve:

```
Function custom_if_formula(condition)
    condition = condition.formula 'any method which take a literal string
    MsgBox(condition)    
End Function
```

P.S. My goal is to implement my own IFS function who behave identically like in Excel 2016. I am just curious if its possible. Tha'ts why I don't want to pass a string as an argument.

Comment: Why can't you just pass the formula as a string rather than a formula?

Comment: What's the purpose of using a UDF here? Why not just use a `Worksheet_Change()` event or something of the like to see whether or not `B1` contains something - is it relative to the formula's position? A UDF should be used to return something to its cell, not to throw a `MsgBox`.

Comment: That would be `MsgBox condition`, without the extra parentheses (note the space the VBE puts between `MsgBox` and `(condition)` - that's your cue for "woopsie, do I really want to evaluate the parenthesised expression as a value and force-pass it `ByVal` to this function?"). That said I've no idea what you're trying to accomplish or what types are involved, everything is an implicit `Variant` here. I'll take a wild guess and go with `MsgBox Application.Evaluate(condition)`.

Comment: My goal is to implement my own IFS function who behave identically like in Excel 2016. I am just curious if its possible. Thats why I don't want to pass a string as an agrument.

Comment: IFS evaluates *everything* passed to it, so I don't see why you need to do anything other than let Excel do the evaluation for you. Otherwise, pass strings and use `evaluate`

Comment: `=IF(AND(condition1, condition2, condition3), value_if_true, value_if_false)` then

Comment: Ok, but for example I would like to add some additional customization to formula like using wildcards: `=IF(B1="*omething")`. If unfortunately excel will evaluate that condition as `FALSE` if B1 cell contains word "string"

Comment: `=if(isnumber(search("omething",B1))`

Comment: @Rory I know its possible to write crazy long nested formula full of other formulas, but its not convenient, easy to make a mistake and hard to modify.

Comment: Unlike this VBA? :) You'll have to pass strings, and parse and evaluate them. Not really simpler, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way how to do it:

```
Function custom_if_formula(condition)
    cell_formula = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Formula 'I get an adress of a cell which call an UDF, and then take all string it contains
    arg = Mid(cell_formula, 12, 100)
    MsgBox(arg)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
Function custom_if_formula(condition)
    If condition.Value = "something" Then MsgBox "something"
End Function
```

Where `B1` is taken as the argument: `=custom_if_formula(B1)`. Putting this in any cell (when `B1` contains the string "something") will return:

[image: img1]

You should really clarify what your intent is here, though. A UDF should return a value to its cell. Right now, it will just say `0` in the UDF's cell. Additionally, looking for "something" could be interpreted as looking for *anything*, and using this kind of verbiage leads to the "Who's on first, what's on second" ordeal...